# Create an excel file if the file is not in the directory and append the row using VB

Tags: excel, vb.net, append

I want to create an excel file base on the date, for example as below

```
 Dim fileDateTime As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

So my filename will be something like this: **20200224.xls**

To create a file is easy. I can just use the following code

```
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
xlWorkBook.SaveAs("c:\Temp\Test\" & fileDateTime & ".xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)
```

My problem is on how

1. To check the file if exist before create the new file
2. Since the filename is based on the date, how can I check if the file is available in the directory according to the date of the day. If the file is available I want to open and to append the row and save the file

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1, check if the file exist

```
          My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("c:\Check.xlsm")
```

returns boolean

2, if exists :

```
    'First get an application instance
    xlApp = GetObject("", "Excel.Application")

    'Second open the workbook you need
    xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\Check.xlsm")

    'set visibility
    xlApp.Visible = True

    ' do not display alerts
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlApp.EnableEvents = False

    ' reference the sheet
    xlSheetRoll = xlBook.Worksheets("FINAL")

    ' find last row
    Dim lRow As Integer = xlSheetRoll .UsedRange.Rows.Count

    ' insert values to new row
    xlSheetRoll.Cells(lRow+1, 1).value = "Report"
    xlSheetRoll.Cells(lRow+1, 2).value = "Report Line"
    xlSheetRoll.Cells(lRow+1, 3).value = "Program"
    xlSheetRoll.Cells(lRow+1, 4).value = "Service"


    'save changes
    xlBook.Save()

    'close workbook
    xlBook.Close(False)

    'quit app
    xlApp.Quit()
```

Comment: Thank you. It inch perfect. Yet, there is an error when it comes to lines ```xlSheetRoll.InsertRow(lRow+1)``` saying System.MissingMemberException and I believed that xlWorkBook.Close(**True**) rather than False.

Comment: I can test the code tmrw, try to declare lRow as public outside method.. what s the value in lRow? Check also data types which go to excel method

Comment: I declare the IRow as public. when I ran it, debug.writeline shows that the IRow detect only 1 even though the number of row that is occupied is more than 1.